# How to get async pathnames to next-intl congif

Tags: next.js, app-router, next-intl

I have a project in next.js 14, and use next-intl for localization. Needs to set pathanes to my next-intl config. If I set pathanames like an oblect, it works nice. But needs to get the list of pathanmes from our admin, to manage URLS from admin.

I try this, but it's doesn't work for me getPathames return for me an object with actual pathnames:

middleware.ts:

```
const getPathnamesAsync = async () => {
  console.log("Fetching pathnames...");
  const pathnames = await getPathnames();
  console.log("Pathnames fetched:", pathnames);
  return pathnames;
};



const intlMiddleware = createIntlMiddleware({
  // A list of all locales that are supported
  // Need update get array of slugs from BE and use readDirectory
  locales,
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  localeDetection: false,
  // If default locale is matched, pathnames work without a prefix (e.g. `/about`)
  // localePrefix: 'as-needed'
  localePrefix: 'always',
  pathnames: getPathnamesAsync
});
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but check [this response on a related GitHub issue](https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/issues/402#issuecomment-1702440478). It seems to be possible to provide an async object by composing middlewares, but there is no corresponding async navigation API available. Maybe you can explain your use case in that thread.